# Capture a set of numbers in sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following string

```
Text1 Text2 v2010.0_1.3 Tue Jun 6 14:38:31 PDT 2017
```

I am trying to capture only `v2010.0_1.3` using

```
echo "Text1 Text2 v2010.0_1.3 Tue Jun 6 14:38:31 PDT 2017" |
sed -nE 's/.*(v.*\s).*/\1/p'
```

and I get the following result `v2010.0_1.3 Tue Jun 6 14:38:31 PDT`. It looks like sed is not stopping the first occurrence of the space, but at the last one. How can I capture only until the first occurence?

Comment: `cut -d' '  -f 3` seems more appropriate than sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using sed

sed's regular expressions are "greedy" (more precisely, they are leftmost-longest matches).  You need to work around that.  For example:

```
$ s="Text1 Text2 v2010.0_1.3 Tue Jun 6 14:38:31 PDT 2017"
$ echo "$s" | sed -nE 's/.*(v[^[:blank:]]*).*/\1/p'
v2010.0_1.3
```

Notes:

1. The expression `(v[^[:blank:]]*)` will capture as a group any string of non-blanks that begins with `v`.
2. `\s` is non-portable (GNU only).  `[[:blank:]]` will work reliably to match blanks and tabs in a unicode-safe way.

### Using awk

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '/^v/' RS=' '
v2010.0_1.3
```

`RS=' '` tells awk to treat a space as a record separator.  `/^v/` will print any record that begins with `v`.

Comment: Note that you should use `(v[^[:blank:]]*)` with only one `[` after the `^`.  As written, your version search stops at an `[` or a blank.  You might also observe that you have unbalanced square brackets in your regex.  It's a curiosity.  You'd have to work hard to spot the trouble, but `T1 T2 v2010.1[3] Tue Jun 6 …` would reveal it, I believe.